# Delete file on ajax post request in laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-4

Trying to delete uploaded images via ajax post request on post edit form. But i am facing some issues, when i press on delete button - it successfully sends ajax post request with image path, then in my controller i am trying to delete that file, but it not deleting it.

Here's my js:

```
(function($) {
    $('.del-image').click(function() {
        var thisUrl = $('.col-md-10 img').attr('src');

        $.ajax({
            method: 'post',
            url: '/del-image',
            data: {imgUrl: thisUrl, id: pageId},
            error: function(e) {
                alert('Error' + e);
            }
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Then in controller i am receiving ajax post request:

```
public function deleteImage() {
    if (Request::ajax()) {
        $path = Input::get('imgUrl');
        File::delete($path);
        return 'ajax request';
    }

    return App::abort(404);
}
```

And in routes.php i have:

```
Route::any('del-image', array('uses' => 'PageController@deleteImage'));
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure that `AJAX` request is being sent to your controller and what you get instead, any error messages ? Where your files are saved (in the public folder) ?

Comment: No error messages, in a console i see the message 'ajax request' when i click delete button.

Comment: Try `try{ File::delete($path); return 'ajax request'; } catch(Exception $e) { dd($e); }`

Comment: Also make sure that `path` is right and has `write` permission.

Comment: I didn't see `success` method in your `AJAX` call, how do you see `'ajax request'` in the `console`.

Comment: my path has write permission, i have tried your code above - i see no errors. Please, take a look at this screenshot: http://i.snag.gy/gaTDc.jpg

Comment: What is the file path ?

Comment: domain.com/uploads/image.jpg

Comment: Just try `File::delete('uploads/image.jpg')`.

Comment: Now my file has been deleted... my $path variable returns - domain.com/uploads/index.jpg, what's wrong?

Comment: Find out how did you generated the `path` ?

Comment: var thisUrl = $('.col-md-10 img').attr('src'); with that code i am getting img src attribute and sending it via post request to a variable $path.

Comment: How did you generated the img `src` from server side?

Comment: I am uploading image via input type file: http://i.snag.gy/aNFwh.jpg

Comment: How did you generate the arc for `$('.col-md-10 img').attr('src')` element ?

Comment: {{ HTML::image($page->image) }}

Comment: Then check what `$page->image` returns ?

Comment: It returns: "uploads/index.jpg", but when i am getting src value with jQuery it takes it with a domain name. So File::delete('http://domain.com/uploads/index.jpg') won't work i guess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try this (To get the file `path` for `uploads/filename.ext`):

```
var  = $('.col-md-10 img').attr('src');
var thisUrlArray = thisUrl.split('/');
thisUrl = 'uploads/' + thisUrlArray.pop();
```

Then use `thisUrl` as your `imgUrl` in `data` parameter of `AJAX` call.

Comment: Thanks, mate! I've used: var thisImg = thisUrl.replace('http://domain.com/', '');